# Adding Circle ProgresBar to box (rectangle wearable)

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app

I have problem with adding circular progress bar to box view. When adding circle surface the circle is too big on my rectangle device. As described in [documentation](https://developer.tizen.org/zh-hans/development/ui-practices/native-application/efl/ui-components/wearable-ui-components/circle-object?langredirect=1#offset) when passing null as circle surface we should be able to set width and height manually, but the circle is not visible. Below is my code for adding content with circle to naviframe.

```
Evas_Object *content, *circle_obj;

content = elm_box_add(ad->naviframe);
evas_object_size_hint_weight_set(content, EVAS_HINT_EXPAND, EVAS_HINT_EXPAND);
evas_object_size_hint_align_set(content, EVAS_HINT_FILL, EVAS_HINT_FILL);
elm_box_horizontal_set(content, EINA_FALSE);

circle_obj = eext_circle_object_add(content, NULL);
evas_object_size_hint_min_set(circle_obj, 150, 150);
eext_circle_object_line_width_set(circle_obj, 20);
eext_circle_object_value_min_max_set(circle_obj, 0.0, 100.0);
eext_circle_object_value_set(circle_obj, 3.0);
evas_object_show(circle_obj);
elm_box_pack_start(content, circle_obj);

elm_naviframe_item_push(ad->naviframe, "Progres Ring", NULL, NULL, content, NULL);
```

Comment: I too never saw the color using any combination of `eext_circle` calls. Did you ever get this to work?

Comment: Yest I have but I ended up using cario to draw it (I needed to add gradient to the circle)